# Split only part of the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

```
let idString = `${address.packname.id}/${address.volume}/${address.colour.id}`;
let componentArray = component.link.string.split("/"); // 297/13L/354,355,356
let coloursArray = componentArray[2].split(",");
    return coloursArray.find((colour) => {
       return (
          `${componentArray[0]}/${componentArray[1]}/${colour}` === idString
       );
    });
```

On the example above (componentArray) where it says 13L this part can also come in as O/S which then doesn't match for the return as it's been split incorrectly. Is there a way to do this so the split skips this part?

Comment: Substring from the index of the first `/` to the index of the last `/`, ignoring all those between

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Introduce the problem before you post any code - In the body of your question, start by expanding on the summary you put in the title. Explain how you encountered the problem you're trying to solve, and any difficulties that have prevented you from solving it yourself. The first paragraph in your question is the second thing most readers will see, so make it as engaging and informative as possible."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A RegEx like this `(/|,)(?<!O/)` should have the desired outcome.
See here for a demonstration: https://regexr.com/5g4mn

It matches slash and comma, but only if the slash wasn't after a `O`. If it is, it will reject the result. This is negative lookbehind. This isnt supported everywhere, but im resonably sure it should be in Java.

Breaking down the RegEx it is three parts. `(/|,)` matches either a slash or a comma. `(?<!)` is the syntax for the lookbehind, the exclamation mark making it negative. `O/` is the expression it is not allowed to match.

Comment: Thanks for the help!